# How can I make two versions of def update in the controller to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I make two versions of def update in the controller to work?

I have a form and admins should be allowed to edit more variables than regular users. Both use the same edit view. Currently I have a form and `def update` in the controller that work but don't distinguish between admins and non-admins.

So now I have added two different strong_params versions to the controller. But how to apply these different versions depending on the type of user?

One way that sort of works is to rewrite def update with an if else statement where it takes one stong_params version if an admin and another strong_params version if non-admin. However, the problem here is that I can't call a before_action on this def update that would test if it's an admin. For security reasons this is probably necessary.

So I'm thinking I need two different def update methods in the controller: 1 for the admin that calls one version of strong_params and for which a before_action is added. And another for non-admins with another version of strong_params (and a different before_action).

**I know how to build this in the controller but don't know how to tell the form in the edit view which def update to use** (or should this be specified in the def edit in the controller?). (In fact, I don't even know how Rails knows that it should call def update (perhaps through resources :users in routes?).) Should I somehow edit the `<%= f.submit "Save changes"` line in the edit view?

Comment: You should handle editable/non-editable attrs in same `update` action instead of creating different `update_*` action

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use forms in this case. Forms is special abstraction layer for representation of model. This is term of php-frameworks (as Zend and so on). In my projects I call it "type" usually. For example:

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

Types:

```
module BaseType
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def model_name
      superclass.model_name
    end

    def name
      superclass.name
    end
  end
end

class PostEditAdminType < Post # model Post is parent class for type
  include BaseType

  attr_accessor :current_user
  attr_accessible :title, :body # can edit both field title and body
end

class PostEditRegularType < Post
  include BaseType

  attr_accessor :current_user
  attr_accessible :body # can edit body field only
end
```

Controller

```
def update
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post = if current_user.admin?
    post.becomes PostEditAdminType
  else
    post.becomes PostEditRegularType
  end

  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to past_path(@past)
  else
    f(:error)
    render :edit
  end
end
```

It's really good practice and the best architecture in same cases in my opinion.

Comment: i would use form objects instead, but okeish

Answer (score 1):

The form_for can only send to one controller action.  You will therefore require a third action which the form_for sends to, and have this action first determine whether you are admin/non-admin and then send you to either of your two 'def update methods' accordingly (taking the parameters with it).  E.g., (and this is entirely pseudo-code)

```
def receive_form

# create variable 'type' that returns whether you are an admin or non-admin

   if type = "Admin"
      # send to your 'def update' for admins, whatever you've named this
      redirect_to admin_update_path
   else
      # send to your 'def update' for non-admins
      redirect_to non_admin_update_path
   end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strong parameter gem, it will only permit some attributes. So you can write some code relates to

```
if current_user.admin?
  params.require(:user).allow :name, :role
else
  params.require(:user).allow :name
end
```

So, if you are an admin user, you can change the role of an user, otherwise, you can edit the name only.

If you want an normal user can only edit his/her account, checkout [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem. It makes more sense, right? If you are a normal user, you should only update your account only.

Sample code using cancancan:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, User, id: user.id
    end
  end
end
```

If you use rails 4 with strong parameter, please don't forget [sanitize your params](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#strong-parameters).

Let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would to have two separate models, one for the `User` and one for the `Role` the user has. You may at some point have more classes than just a regular user and admin, so this method simplifies adding more roles in the long run.

How this is done:

1. Create `Roles` model that has one column which is `name`
2. The `User` model will have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` relationship
3. The `Role` model will have a `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` relationship
4. Because of the many-to-many relationship you should create a join table. The join table should be named after the models in alpha-numeric order. Therefore your migration should look like this `rails g migration CreateRolesUsersTable`
5. The `has_and_belongs_to_many` statements create variables that automatically use the join table to look up their values. You can look into these.
6. You can check if things are set up properly by writing:

   `admin_role = Role.find_by(name: “admin”)
   user.roles.include?(admin_role)`
7. You can also add your own methods to the `User` model for your own use. Here is a sample of mine:

   ```
   def admin?
       self.is_role_by_name?("admin")
   end
   ```

   def add_role(role)
       roles << role
   end

   def add_role_by_name(role_name)
       role = Role.find_by(name: role_name)
       add_role(role)
   end

   def remove_role(role)
       roles.delete(role)
   end

   def remove_role_by_name(role_name)
       role = Role.find_by(name: role_name)
       remove_role(role)
   end

   def is_role?(role)
       roles.to_a.include?(role)
   end

   def is_role_by_name?(role_name)
       role = Role.find_by(name: role_name)
       is_role?(role)
   end
8. Now in your view you can have the following to show certain fields of the form:

   ```
   <% if @user.admin? %>
      input whatever here...
   <% end %>
   ```